# WCF Client Proxy C# How Can I Change User on the fly?

Tags: c#, wcf, proxy

I have a WCF DUPLEX Client Proxy that connects to a Service - I control both sources of code. I would like to know how I can change the user on the fly. So for example my client application starts up, it has data that gets updated because it has connected tot he WCF service which the singleton service host pushes data to it. I would like to be able to have the User of the Client Application to be able to change and the proxy that is already communicating to change its connection to use those credentials. (The proxy is running ) ; is this possible and if so how would I implement it ?

Comment: You can't, as far as I know.  You'll need to create a new proxy with the new credentials.

Comment: @Tim - that is what I feared, my reasoning was that I did not want the previous user to be disconnected unless the new user was validated. I guess I can leave the one client proxy running, try to connect with a new client and on success get rid of the old.. seems like a kludge (I kind of understand the reasoning if I can't do this - but I would like to as it would be a seamless transition).

Comment: Yes it is not possible as Tim stated. On the other hand caching Proxies is dangerous because on exception the channel is automatically closed and any calls thereafter will fail. Thus you would need to code in re-establish connection to make the fail-over transparent, not worth it.